# Animate Stackview's change in layout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

```
<StackLayout>
    <ActivityIndicator VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" x:Name="activityIndicator" Color="Red" IsRunning="true" />
    <Button x:Name="btnDecline" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Clicked="Handle_Submit" Text="Submit" BackgroundColor="Red" TextColor="Black" HeightRequest="50" />
</StackLayout>
```

If the activity indicator is visible and then its `IsVisible` property is set to false, is it possible to have the stack view smoothly animate away the free space?

At the moment, it snaps. I've tried animating the height of the activity indicator to zero but it's horribly jerky.